# Align columns against one another by row

Tags: string, bash, text-alignment

Assume a file with three columns of strings.

```
> cat file
foo foo bar
bar baz
baz qux
qux
```

What, if any, command in bash could be used to align these columns against one another by row? The correct output would look like as follows:

```
> sought_command file
foo foo
bar     bar
baz baz
qux qux
```

Comment: What if two of the same word occur in the same column?

Comment: Why is there extra space in case of `bar       bar` ?

Comment: @anishsane I think what the OP wants is to put the same words on the same line while retaining their "columns".

Comment: ^^ Oh, got it now...

Comment: @anishsane User _4ae1e1_ is correct. I am looking for is code that aligns the columns in such a fashion that each line eventually contains the same word, but maintains the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'max<NF{max=NF} # Get max number of columns
    { #For every input line,
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
           b[$i]++;   # Record all possible tokens, like foo, bar etc.
           a[i$i]++;  # Record their column indices
       }
    }

    END{
           for(i in b) #Get max length of all the tokens (for printing)
               if(c<length(i))
                   c=length(i); 

           for(i in b) # For each token,
           {
              for(j=1;j<=max;j++){ # For every column,
                  if(a[j i]) d = i; # Decide, if we want to print it, or left blank...
                  else d="";

                  printf "%-"(c+5)"s", d; # Print the token, or blank space
              }
              print ""; # Print newline after every tokens line.
           }
       }' test.input

foo     foo             
baz     baz             
qux     qux             
bar             bar
```

Regarding the order of the input vs output data: I don't think there is any input tokens order, because below input data should also give the similar output.

```
foo foo
bar
baz baz bar
qux qux
```

It is possible to maintain the order of the token, in which they first appeared. e.g. in above (reordered) case, it would be foo, bar, baz, qux.

```
$ awk 'max<NF{max=NF} # Get max number of columns
{ #For every input line,
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){

        if(!b[$i]++)
            token[j++]=$i;
        a[i$i]++;  # Record their column indices
    }
}

END{
    for(i in b) #Get max length of all the tokens (for printing)
        if(max_len<length(i))
            max_len=length(i); 

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc";

    for(i in token) { # For each token,
        for(j=1;j<=max;j++){ # For every column,
            if(a[j token[i]]) d = token[i]; # Decide, if we want to print it, or left blank...
            else d="";

            printf "%-"(max_len+5)"s", d; # Print the token, or blank space
        }
        print ""; # Print newline after every tokens line.
    }
}' test.input.reordered

foo     foo             
bar             bar     
baz     baz             
qux     qux
```

Comment: Wow! It works as expected. This is some intense _awk_ code. I take my hat off to you!

Comment: Looking closer into your code, I noticed that the original order of the lines is not maintained. By that order, the second line should be "bar" not "baz". What would it take to maintain the original order?

Comment: If the output of your code is saved to variable _out_, then the following code will re-establish the original line order: `for i in $(awk '{print $1}' file); do grep ^$i out; done`

Comment: There is no original order of lines, since the original data is just a pattern. See the edit.