# Aligning text columns of different size and content

Tags: optimization, pattern-matching, pseudocode, text-alignment

In a [past posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219629/align-columns-against-one-another-by-row), I asked about commands in *Bash* to align text columns against one another by row. It has become clear to me that the desired task (i.e., aligning text columns of different size and content by row) is much more complex than initially anticipated and that the proposed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219629/align-columns-against-one-another-by-row?answertab=votes#tab-top), while acceptable for the past posting, is insufficient on most empirical data sets. Thus, I would like to query the community on the following pseudocode. Specifically, I would like to know if and in what way the following pseudocode could be optimized.

Assume a file with *n* columns of strings. Some strings might be missing, others might be duplicated. The longest column may not be the first one listed in the file, but shall be the reference column. The order of the rows of this reference column must be maintained.

```
> cat file  # where n=3; first row contains column headers
CL1 CL2 CL3
foo foo bar
bar baz qux
baz qux
qux foo
    bar
```

Pseudocode attempt 1 (totally inadequate):

```
Shuffle columns so that columns ordered by size (i.e., longest column is first in matrix)
Rownames = strings of first column (i.e., of longest column)
For rownames
  For (colname among columns 2:end)
    if (string in current cell == rowname) {keep string in location}
    if (string in current cell != rowname) {
      if (string in current cell == rowname of next row) {add row to bottom of table; move each string of current column one row down}
      if (string in current cell != rowname of next row) {add row to bottom of table; move each string of all other columns one row down}
    }
```

Order columns by size:

```
> cat file_columns_ordered_by_size
CL2 CL1 CL3
foo foo bar
baz bar qux
qux baz 
foo qux 
bar
```

Sought output:

```
> my_code_here file_columns_ordered_by_size
CL2 CL1 CL3
foo foo 
    bar bar
baz baz    
qux qux qux
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:  Ugh, this doesn't produce the output you wanted.  I guess I don't understand the problem.  Maybe it will help, anyway.**

If you don't mind slurping the entire table into memory, associative arrays (hashes) would work.  (Or you can use trees, maps, dictionaries, etc.) There would be one for each column, mapping strings (found in the cells of that column) to the number of times that string is found in that column.  Let's name the hashes after their column headers.  After slurping, they would look something like this:

```
CL2 = {'foo':2, 'baz':1, 'bar':1, 'qux':1}
CL1 = {'foo':1, 'baz':1, 'bar':1, 'qux':1}
CL3 = {'bar':1, 'qux':1}

# Store the columns in an array
columnCounts = [CL2, CL1, CL3]
```

Then write a loop that produces the output, deleting from the associative arrays at each iteration:

```
while (columnCounts still has at least one non-empty hash) {
    key = the hash-key that is present in most (a plurality) of the hashes
    for each hash in columnCounts {
        if the key is in the hash {
            print key
            Decrement hash[key]
        }
        else {
            print whitespace
        }
    }

    print newline
}
```